# How can I get twitter current user's gender

Tags: twitter, twitter-anywhere

I have reviewed the twitter documentation @anywhere 
where I can use User Object Properties but in the userdata I don't find the gender property.

Answer (score 8):

When you create a twitter account it never asks for gender, so you cant get it through the API.

You would need some kind of AI to determine it.

Comment: thanks for the reply I just new to twitter and twitter api.
just in my CreatAccountConnectWithOtherSocNet method has a gender argument just in this case i will add gender field in my interface

Comment: I tried this : http://api.namsor.com/onomastics/api/json/gendre/dummyFirstName/dummyLastName]. Still it gave me response as gender MALE

Answer (score 1):

Demographic data such as `gender` and `age` are not available from the API -- and not always appropriate as Twitter accounts can represent many things not limited to persons alive or dead.

Answer (score 1):

Latest answer @2016

You still can't get twitter users' gender but can you can deduce it with some workable apis.

See node-cheat [gender_by_name](https://github.com/zishon89us/node-cheat/blob/master/random/small_tasks/gender_by_name.js) for all reasonable and tested solutions.